# jQuery cookie plugin creates same cookie instead of read it

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, httpcookie, jquery-cookie

I've this:

```
// connect to MemberHub
function connect() {

    // get unique id cookie
    var uid = $.cookie('UniqueID', { path: '/' });

    member.server.connect(uid).done(function (result) {
        if (result.msg == 'success') {
            // notify user  
            $('#log').append($('<li>', { html: 'Connected to MemberHUB' }));
        }
    });
}
```

Each time I try to read cookie it creates same cookie instead of read it.

[image]

**Update:** Here is how I assign cookies:

```
    public static HttpCookie Create(string name, string value, 
        DateTime expires, HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(name)
        {
            Value = value,
            Expires = expires,
            Secure = true,
            HttpOnly = false,
            Path = "/"
        };

        httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        return cookie;
    }
```

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: If you remove the path, does the same error occur?

Comment: Yes, still getting two cookies with same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.cookie` is only read access if no other parameters (but the cookie's name) are supplied to the method *[See [the source](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js#L42-L62)]*

If you're interested in reading it, just supply `$.cookie('UniqueID')` and remove the second parameter.

As an FYI, `path` (and other cookie properties) are only relevant when assigning a value, not retrieving. In other words, you don't need to supply `path:'/'` to get cookies that are applied to that path, `document.cookie` should natively perform that check.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I remove the `Path` I get null value for cookie.

Comment: And how are you assigning it? The value is the second parameter with prongs being the third.

Comment: @SaberAmani: you've confirmed it's being assigned at the client level? I don't see any reason why you can't access it other than if there was nothing to access in the first place.